# Main water valve just turns, turns and turns

Tags: plumbing

During recent freezing temps, I closed the main water valve, there is one outside and another in the garage. The one outside knob turns fully open and fully closed.

The other valve     in the garage just turns and turns with no change in pressure inside the house. (*There is no/very low  pressure in the house*).

The valves have a round metal handles.

Comment: Please edit your question so it is not in all capitol letters. It unnecessary and  the equivalent of shouting. Also, proper punctuation please.   Some of the comma's should be periods.

Comment: Fairly common for consumer gate valves to fail internally as you described; especially if made in China ( in my experience ).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn!_Turn!_Turn!

Comment: It's vaguely possible that the knob has simply come loose on the shaft.

Answer (score 2):

Having updated a lot of old homes this is not an unheard of problem. What I have found on old gate valves that in some cases they close and seal well but when opening the gate block stays in place and the threads are not quite engaging and lifting the gate block. I have been able to re engage the gate by pulling the valve stem and using a hook to pull the gate up (I have turned off well pumps and water mains to do this) put everything back together knowing the next time it was turned off it would do it again but that gave me time to find replacement parts.

So I believe the gate block dropped off the valve stem or the end was rotted off. In most of the cases I was able to find replacement parts. On several cases the design was different and the entire valve had to be replaced. But pulling the gate up got the water flowing. (After the valve was reassembled).

Comment: *re engage the gate*, +1. Push down on the knob while closing. Pull on it while opening. The trick is to get the threads to lock tighter (and keep them that way: push/pull) than the friction of the gate.